# Why is sharepoint (onedrive) giving the error "Links to external workbooks are not supported and have been disabled" when there are no external links?

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, sharepoint

I have tried everything I can think of, and everything the internet has to offer:

- Find function
- Go-To Special, Objects - manually inspect each
- An add-in for finding external links
- Manually searching charts and chart names
- Manually searching conditional formatting
- Manually searching all new cells since the error started appearing
- Data - connections list (empty)
- Formulas - name manager list (empty)
- Maybe more - I'm losing track

There just aren't any external links! But the error persists. There are no pivot tables, there are no tables, there are no macros. Any other ideas? Please?

PS. the error actually isn't causing problems - everything works, it's just a bar at the top of the page in SharePoint, but people I work with are panicking and I can't convince them that it's not a issue, so now it is.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of the error by checking out the file, editing IN EXCEL (and only changing the spelling in an arbitrary text cell), uploading, and checking back in. Bizarre, but issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Press 'Tell me what you want to do' at the top of the excel and search for 'remove links'.

Click links.

This should show any external links to excel files or other sources. Click them and click break links. Then save and upload back into sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SharePoint. I fixed it by opening the name manager and deleting a name that had a reference to another workbook.

Here's a link with more good info: [Removing phantom external links in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/938449/removing-phantom-external-links-in-excel?rq=1)