# Phantom Sharepoint Links

Tags: sharepoint, links, ghost

When I open my workbook and hit "enable content"  Excel attempts to open about 10 different references to Sharepoint.  However, I do not want or need any Sharepoint links in my workbook.  I have combed all the cells, searched in edit links, connections and everywhere I could think of to find why it's referencing Sharepoint.  My only guess is that a Sharepoint link was being used before and now I have these "ghost" links.. How do I remove them as this is limiting my ability to do other things in this file.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing phantom external links in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/938449/removing-phantom-external-links-in-excel)

Comment: I looked at that ^ thread to and it did not help.  I am on an office computer and cannot use the FindLink software anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OK. In excel under the formulas tab there is an option called "Name Manager".  That showed me all of the sharepoint links that I couldn't for the life of me find.
I deleted all those references I didn't need and it works better.

FYI, Name Manager was clutch for me.